# UIKit is nowhere to be found?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, uikit

I can't find UIKit.framework anywhere: it's nowhere in my /System/Library/Framework and I can't add it via Build Phase because it's not there to select. I have installed and re-installed xcode and it's not showing up. It doesn't seem to be directly downloadable either. Any ideas?

Comment: UIKit is for iOS development, not OS X development. AppKit is for OS X, although you usually just use the Cocoa umbrella framework.

Comment: Are they not all installed under the xcode framework?

Comment: The question is tagged "osx", so I assumed you were trying to develop for OS X. `/System/Library` is for the actual running system. If you're looking for development files, look inside Xcode.app/Contents/Developer.

Comment: @KenThomases I'm sorry, that was confusing and I shouldn't have tagged that. Nonetheless, even if I am just developing for OSX that framework should still download with xcode, should it not?

Comment: I think it should be included, but not in /System/Library. It will be inside Xcode, I think. In Xcode's Preferences, on the Downloads tab, does it list an iOS SDK? If so, there should be a button to download it.

Comment: Underneath downloads there is "components" and "documentation", but there isn't an iOS SDK. There is iOS 7/7.1 simulators, but that doesn't seem to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is indeed meant to be a question for a Mac OS X application instead of an iOS application @Ken Thomases reply is true. If this question is about making an iOS application with Xcode on Mac OS X then it might be possible your project file is a bit broken. I had to deal with this some weeks ago when all of a sudden I could not add an audio framework.

- Open Xcode but close all windows so no projects are open
- Press CMD-SHIFT-2 to go to the Organizer
- Go to Projects
- Select your project
- Press on the Delete button on the line of Derived Data
- Restart Xcode
- Open your project
- Wait until your project has been analyzed

Alternatively you can show the contents of the package of your project file by CTRL-clicking it and selecting Show Package Contents. There are a lot of user based files there, some might be corrupt. Throw these files away and try again. Backup just to be sure.

Your project's settings should look something like this:
[image]

Build phases:

[image]

It's important that you target iOS and that UIKit and Foundation are there

If they're not, try to create a new project

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I am still getting 'no such module UIKit'

Comment: Is this an existing project with a lot of code or are you just starting? What happens if you create a new project? It's pretty easy to start a new project and import all of your files in one go.

Comment: No, it's a new project and I am relatively new to working in xcode (a web developer experimenting with some new stuff). Was trying to replicate some small projects to figure things out. It's my understanding UIKit comes with xcode, but when I try "import UIKit" I just continue to get 'no such module UIKit.' I've tried making a new project, etc.

Comment: You're right it should be. I've updated my posting with some screenshots

Comment: Okay, I figured this out. It was a very simple mistake I was making, but your answer was nonetheless very helpful in allowing me to figure out what I was doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear you've figured it out. Sometimes explaining the problem to other people leads you to think about things you've overseen all the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55262/discussion-between-departamento-b-and-thesublimeobject).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right Platform set under Playground Settings

[image: Playground settings under Utilities Pane]

Comment: Thanks, but this question was answered correct like 2 years ago.

Comment: @thesublimeobject  Hmm.. I came across this question when I had exactly the same problem the question describes and the correct answer wasn't helpful for me so I shared what worked for me. I believe this platform is for helping everyone, not only the original questioner.

Comment: yeah, i'm not really sure why i answered like that. it's possible something could have changed since the original answer that makes your addition helpful; i'm not really sure. i appreciate your input.